# iterating over a list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using pyton 3.2
I have the following dictionary:

```
a = {"fruits":["apple","mangoes","grapes"],"colour":["apple","orange","grapes"],"number":["1","2","3"]}
```

I need to iterate over this list of dictionary and I want to create a new dictionary b in which values in fruits is the same value in colours:

```
 b = {"fruits":["apple","grapes"],"colour":["apple", "grapes"],"number":["1","3"]}
```

i was thinking this could work but am lost from then on:

```
b = {}
for item in a:
   if x in a[item]:
```

...... dont know what to do now?

How can i do this without using itertools at all? 
Is there a general function that i can use for any dictionary besides the one that i have listed?

Comment: It's actually a dictionary with lists as values, not a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're better off using a `set`:

```
b = {"fruits": list(set(a['fruits']).intersection(a['colour'])}
b['colour'] = b['fruits']  # or maybe make a copy here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
a = {"fruits":["apple","mangoes","grapes"],"colour":["apple","orange","grapes"]}
b = {}

b['fruits'], b['colour'] = [], []

for fruit in a['fruits']:
    if fruit in a['colour']:
        b['fruits'].append(fruit)
        b['colour'].append(fruit)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want numbers in the result dictionary, you can do it this way...

**Code:**

```
a = {"fruits":["apple","mangoes","grapes"],"colour":["apple","orange","grapes"],"number":["1","2","3"]}

b = dict()
b['fruits'] = b['colour'] = [x for x in a['fruits'] if x in a['colour']]

print b
```

**Output:**

```
{'colour': ['apple', 'grapes'], 'fruits': ['apple', 'grapes']}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if i want numbers in the result dictionary, how would i do it? if i want the following output (b = {"fruits":["apple","grapes"],"colour":["apple", "grapes"],"number":["1","3"]}), how do i do it?

Comment: Just add this line ... b['number'] = [a['number'].__getitem__(a['fruits'].index(x)) for x in b['fruits']] next to b['fruits'] = b['colour'] = [x for x in a['fruits'] if x in a['colour']]

Answer (score 0):

```
b = {}
for fruit in a['fruits']:
    if fruit in a['colour']:
        b.setdefault('fruits', [])   # set if key is not present
        b.setdefault('colour', [])
        b.setdefault('number', [])
        b['fruits'].append(fruit)
        b['colour'].append(fruit)
        b['number'].append(a['number'][a['fruits'].index(fruit)])
```